# Scrapy select immediate children

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to find immediate `.col.group` children of certain div. How can I do this?

```
divs = response.css(div.container)
children = divs[0].css('>.col.group') # this doesn't work
```

How can this be written with both `css` and `xpath`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a current node concept. So you can do that with CSS. But thing is Scrapy allows you to mix CSS and XPATH. So you can mix them quite well

```
divs = response.css(div.container)
children = divs[0].xpath('./*[contains(@class, 'col')]') # this doesn't work
```

Comment: Ho to write and class `group`?

Comment: `children = divs[0].xpath("./*[contains(@class, 'col')][contains(@class, 'group')]")`